# What does it mean when an extension is "Removed" from the Chrome Marketplace?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We just got a message from the Google Chrome Web Store saying that:

> We regret to inform you that your item has been removed from the Chrome Web Store.

This is a shock, because our extension has 20k users, and we didn't know it had any kind of problem.

What does it mean that our extension is "removed" from the store? Does this mean it's uninstalled from browsers? Disabled? Will our users have to re-install it?

Answer (score 0):

Google included [a link](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/one_stop_support) in their email, but the page didn't answer the question, so I asked support. I asked:

> 1. When an extension is removed from the marketplace, does that uninstall it from all browsers? After an issue is fixed, do users have to re-install it?

They replied:

> No, it would not be deleted from your user's browsers. However, it would be disabled by the browser until your extension becomes available in the store again.

I think that's a distinction almost without meaning, since we now have to get all our users to re-enable the extension, which is about as hard as re-installing it. We don't collect email addresses from our users, so this is really not great.

It looks like we missed ***one*** email from Google saying that we needed screenshots and that "Extension’s description provided is not sufficient to understand the complete functionality of the extension."